# How to execute JUnitTests in Runtime-Workspace (JUnit-Plugin-Test)?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, junit-runner

I'm facing a problem with JUnit tests. I have written an JUnitRunner which is used to execute the WrapperTest.

The WrapperTest generates a plain JUnit-Test and a needed file. If I want to execute the methods of the generated test, my Runner searchs in the Developement-Workspace for the "NeededClass".

I'm generating the needed class in the JUnit-Workspace and i want the tests to use this generated class file, so i can delete this file in my Develop-Workspace.

So, how do I execute the generated test in the JUnit-Workspace? (He shall look in the JUnit-Workspace for the needed file)[image]

edit: OK, i found out, it's a ClassLoader problem... The Develop Workspace got another ClassLoader than the JUnit-Workspace, this causes weired errors, for example that a "class isn't the identical class Exception"  (**java.lang.ClassCastException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cannot be cast to org.junit.runner.JUnitCore**). Looks like i have to fix this problem by reflection, what is very dirty.

Answer (score -1):

Look into Maven and its [build lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference). You can wire the code generation you are doing into the generate-test-sources phase and then have it participate as normal in the test phase.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587353/maven-how-to-handle-generated-sources-for-testonly) for an example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I provided an answer roughly with the same level of detail OP provided in the question.

Comment: So what? It's still a link-only answer in the sense that you haven't explained how to do anything - and if the link changes, the answer becomes useless.

Comment: The link is not that important for my answer. The key element is looking into the Maven build lifecycle to wire up code generation in a way it can be tested. Even though my answer is short does not mean there is anything wrong with it. If OP had provided more detail in the question I could have given a more detailed answer. As it stands, answering in more detail is likely to miss the mark.

Comment: We'll have to agree to differ. Just FTR, I have not voted your answer down.

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the feedback.